# Formulation of State Space Models

Tags: state-space-models

I have seen the following formulation of state space models:

$$ 
z_{t + 1} = A z_t + B u_t + \epsilon_t \\
y_t = C z_t + D u_t + \delta_t
$$

But sometimes it is also written as follows:
$$ 
z_{t} = A z_{t-1} + B u_t + \epsilon_t \\
y_t = C z_t + D u_t + \delta_t
$$
Why are there different formulations for computing the next state?

When to use which formulation?